# MMA2 "Error loading song file" message every time I click the "Edit Level" button

Tags: beat-saber

In MMA2 (*Beat Saber*), every time I click the "Edit Level" button it gives me this message: "Error loading song file".

[image: screenshot of error message]

I have tried anything and everything I can think of. I have also discovered that when I try to delete or rename the song file it crashes file explorer, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case, but the file must be an Ogg Vorbis file (ogg). Not sure about the file explorer crash.

Comment: Thought it might be worth mentioning that Beat Saber can also handle WAV (.wav) files.

Comment: Didn't know that to be honest. I've always seen people say OGG.